# phpThumb - is it possible to add more than one filter using the setParameter method?

Tags: php, parameters, filter, phpthumb

I'm building a thumbnail constructor with phpThumb (the James Heinrich implementation available [here](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/phpThumb)). Basically, I'm encapsulating the `phpThumb` class to build thumbnails with a syntax like this:

```
$thumbnail = \Helpers\Images::getThumbnail("/assets/images/sample.png", [
    "width" => 150,
    "filters" => [
        "grayscale"
    ]
]);
```

This checks if the image I'm asking a thumbnail for with the given set of options and filters exists and, if it does, it just gives me the URL to this resource. In case it doesn't, it processes the image, save the resulting thumbnail and gives me the URL to this newly created resource.

So far, so good. My problem comes when I try to add more than one filter like this:

```
$thumbnail = \Helpers\Images::getThumbnail("/assets/images/sample.png", [
    "width" => 150,
    "filters" => [
        "blur" => 25,
        "grayscale"
    ]
]);
```

Internally, I do this:

```
    /**
     * more filter cases here
     */
} elseif ($filter === "blur") {
    if (!empty($parameters)) {
        if (sizeof($parameters === 1)) {
            $value = current($parameters);

            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                if ($value >= 0) {
                    if ($value <= 25) {
                        $phpthumb->setParameter("fltr", implode("|", [
                            $filters[$filter],
                            $value
                        ]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} elseif ($filter === "brightness") {
    /**
     * more filter cases here
     */
```

`$filters[$filter]` is just an associative array with the different filter opcodes like `usm` (unsharpen), `gblr` (gaussian blur) and so on.

Seems like invoking the `setParameter()` method multiple times is not working like I want (or like it should).

Is there a way to stack different filters together using the OO approach?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it by changing the core logic. Calling the `setParameter()` method out of the loop with all operations stored in array format fixed my problem.